# How to preload images without interfering with rest of the page's.. stuff?

Tags: javascript, html

Several problems with this:

1. Older stack posts suggest using js to just create a new Image().src =... but this no longer seems to work
2. I had some success by actually including the image in the page in an invisible way (while not using straight up visibility:hidden or such) 
   but this kinda stutters all other DOM activity on the page while the images are loading
3. Can't use ajax to prefetch the resources due to cross-domain policy

So basically, is there a known method to preload images without messing with DOM?

Comment: Why don't 1, 2 work? Can you post some code?

Comment: I don't know why not, it just doesn't. Try it on any modern browser

Comment: I would, if you'd post the code.

Comment: Did you try <link rel="preload"?

Comment: @JohnBupit code? Its like 2 lines but ok..  Image().src="someBigImageFileLink.bmp";setTimeout(function(){querySelector("body").style.backgroundImage="url('someBigImageFileLink.bmp')";}, 1000);

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try loading images in a container that is off the screen. The container would be absolutely positioned with a high positive or negative position attribute(top,left,right or bottom)
2. You can try using the more modern "prefetch" technique. Doesn't work across browsers but you can read it here
   https://css-tricks.com/prefetching-preloading-prebrowsing/

Also I dont get the DOM stutter that you mentioned in your question
Please check https://jsfiddle.net/8gmaet0p/.

```
<div style="position: absolute; top:-999999px">
  <img src="http://cdn.londonandpartners.com/assets/73295-640x360-london-skyline-ns.jpg" style="height:1px; width: 1px;" onload="show()"/>
</div>
```

The animation works fine while the image is loading and onload the show function is called.

Comment: I dont get why would the DOM 'stutter' if some resources are being loaded in 1px x 1px div. May be you can share some example code.

Comment: there are other things poking the DOM all the time, those other things are a way too big of a pile of code to put on stack.

I tried your second suggestion, doesn't seem to be doing anything when added dynamically

Comment: css transforms are known to bypass DOM completely

Comment: You need to share code of what exactly are you trying to do other than loading images that is getting blocked.